# How to use mathjax with mustachejs template

Tags: json, mathjax, mustache

I am using mathjax for display mathematics formula.
It works fine when I write an example like this in my html file:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
   MathJax.Hub.Config({
   tex2jax: { inlineMath: [['$','$'],['\\(','\\)']] }
});
</script>
....
<div id="problems">
   \begin{equation}
      \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}
   \end{equation}
</div>
```

Let's suppose I want to write the formula in a json file.
I load the formula from the json file by using mustache.js

```
var html = Mustache.to_html(tpl, data);
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#problems').html(html);
});
```

It displays the **LaTeX Symbols/Script** instead of the Math Symbol.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you post your json file, please?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,"problems"])` after setting the HTML for the problems div.  See the [MathJax Documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/typeset.html) for details.